# If Statement for "RAG" status based on Aging

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have an aging column in SharePoint, that I would like to reflect show **RAG (Red, Amber and Green)** status based on the amount of days each case has aged.

> Aging<15 Green
>
> Aging >=15<30 Amber
>
> Aging >=30 Red

Status can just display words "Green", "Amber" and "Red".

What would be the if statement to achive this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use on SPO formatting columns with JSON, [documentation here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting).

Answer (score 0):

For SPO, as Zdeněk Vinduška mentioned, you can customise SharePoint Online Columns Using JSON – Column Formatter.

For SharePoint On-premise, you can use the methods in below articles:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/76823954-318d-413f-b753-b168631d73ef/javascript-to-colour-code-list-items-based-on-date-parameters?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

https://pathtosharepoint.wordpress.com/2008/09/01/apply-color-coding-to-your-sharepoint-lists/